# Hibernate - storing history

Tags: database, hibernate

I have to storing history of my table.
For example if I have entity:

```
@Entity
@EntityListener(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneartedValue(startegy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @CreatedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date createDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date lastModifiedDate;
}
```

Should I create new entity PersonHistory with field Person, and before update Person saving state of Person as PersonHistory?

Is the easier way?

Answer (score 2):

Do you need to store every change on your person, or is it enough to see when it was saved the last time?

If you need some kind of versioning, maybe you should take a look at [Hibernate Envers](http://hibernate.org/orm/envers/)

If it´s enough to see, when the person was modified the last time, your approach is okay i think.

You could create a history table on your own like this:

```
|ID | Field | changedate | before | after   |
+---+-------+------------+--------+---------+
| 1 | name  | timestamp  |Smith   | Smithes |
```

But before you do this by hand, I would prefer envers.